# How to initialize a local struct in MASM assembly

Tags: assembly, struct, x86, masm

I want to initialize a local struct on the stack.

```
Records         STRUCT
data1           DWORD   ?
data2           DWORD   ?
data3           DWORD   ?
data4           DWORD   ?
Records         ENDS

                .CODE
main:
                mov     ebp, esp
                sub     esp, SIZEOF Records
```

How do I make a named instance of `struct Records` that I can then use to initialize the data members? I want to use the `struct` directive with the dot operator and not pointer addition.

I started out by allocating space for the struct, then what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use the power of the `PROC` directive to define functions<sup>1</sup> and the `LOCAL` directive to allocate variables in a function. The assembler will deal with the prologue and epilogue code and you can associate a type with the local.

You could write a function that looks like:

```
main PROC
    LOCAL rec1: Records
    mov rec1.data1, 1
    mov rec1.data2, 2
    mov rec1.data3, 3
    mov rec1.data4, 4

    ret
main ENDP
```

The code will allocate space on the stack for a variable called `rec1` and the remaining lines initialize the structure fields with the values 1,2,3,4. The generated assembly code would look something like:

> ```
> Segment: _TEXT DWORD USE32 00000033 bytes
> 0000                            _main:
> 0000  55                                push            ebp
> 0001  8B EC                             mov             ebp,esp
> 0003  83 EC 10                          sub             esp,0x00000010
> 0006  C7 45 F0 01 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr -0x10[ebp],0x00000001
> 000D  C7 45 F4 02 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr -0xc[ebp],0x00000002
> 0014  C7 45 F8 03 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr -0x8[ebp],0x00000003
> 001B  C7 45 FC 04 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr -0x4[ebp],0x00000004
> 0022  C9                                leave
> 0023  C3                                ret
> ```

The assembler created a stack frame and computed all the offsets on the stack for you relative to *EBP*. If you wanted to get the address of `rec1` into a register and work with it as a structure you can use `LEA` to get the effective address of the variable on the stack and use `ASSUME` to apply a pointer type to it:

```
main PROC
    LOCAL rec1: Records
    lea eax, [rec1]
    ASSUME eax: ptr Records
    mov [eax].data1, 1
    mov [eax].data2, 2
    mov [eax].data3, 3
    mov [eax].data4, 4
    ret
main ENDP
```

The generated assembly code would be:

> ```
> Segment: _TEXT DWORD USE32 00000035 bytes
> 0000                            _main:
> 0000  55                                push            ebp
> 0001  8B EC                             mov             ebp,esp
> 0003  83 EC 10                          sub             esp,0x00000010
> 0006  8D 45 F0                          lea             eax,-0x10[ebp]
> 0009  C7 00 01 00 00 00                 mov             dword ptr [eax],0x00000001
> 000F  C7 40 04 02 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr 0x4[eax],0x00000002
> 0016  C7 40 08 03 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr 0x8[eax],0x00000003
> 001D  C7 40 0C 04 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr 0xc[eax],0x00000004
> 0024  C9                                leave
> 0025  C3                                ret
> ```

You can use the `LOCAL` directive to create an array of types as well. You can then initialize elements of individual records in the array. This example allocates space on the stack for an array of 4 `Records` called `rec1` and initializes the the third element (array index 2 since array element numbering is zero based):

```
main PROC
    LOCAL rec1[4]: Records
    ; Compute address of third Record structure in array
    lea eax, [rec1]
    ASSUME eax: ptr Records
    add eax, 2*(SIZEOF Records)
    ; Initialize the the third Record structure
    mov [eax].data1, 1
    mov [eax].data2, 2
    mov [eax].data3, 3
    mov [eax].data4, 4
    ret
main ENDP
```

The generated assembly code would be:

> ```
> Segment: _TEXT DWORD USE32 00000038 bytes
> 0000                            _main:
> 0000  55                                push            ebp
> 0001  8B EC                             mov             ebp,esp
> 0003  83 EC 40                          sub             esp,0x00000040
> 0006  8D 45 C0                          lea             eax,-0x40[ebp]
> 0009  83 C0 20                          add             eax,0x00000020
> 000C  C7 00 01 00 00 00                 mov             dword ptr [eax],0x00000001
> 0012  C7 40 04 02 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr 0x4[eax],0x00000002
> 0019  C7 40 08 03 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr 0x8[eax],0x00000003
> 0020  C7 40 0C 04 00 00 00              mov             dword ptr 0xc[eax],0x00000004
> 0027  C9                                leave
> 0028  C3                                ret
> ```

I split the `LEA` and the `ADD` into separate instructions to better illustrate what is going on. It can be simplified by removing the `ADD` and using `LEA` to add the offset to the base pointer of the `rec1` array directly. Preferably it would have been written as:

```
    lea eax, [rec1 + 2*(SIZEOF Records)]
    ASSUME eax: ptr Records
```

---

### Structures at Global Scope

If you create structures at global scope (not locals on the stack) you can declare and initialize them this way:

```
                .DATA
rec2 Records <1,2,3,4>
```

Each field in the structure is separated by a comma. The structure would appear in the `_DATA` segment like this:

> ```
> Segment: _DATA DWORD USE32 00000010 bytes
> 0000  01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 ................
> ```

The data is printed in bytes. Each individual DWORD appears with LSB (least significant byte) to MSB (most significant byte). If displayed as DWORDs they would appear as

> ```
> 0000 00000001 00000002 00000003 00000004
> ```

---

### Footnotes

- <sup>1</sup>I used a `.MODEL` directive at the top of the assembly file to assume *C* style calling convention by default:

  ```
  .386
  .model flat, C
  ```

Comment: Nice examples showing what the MASM high-level stuff actually compiles into :)

Comment: @PeterCordes : Generally I wouldn't have to do it but when the assembler generates code for you it is important to see what goes on under the hood. I didn't mention specifically though that the epilogue (`leave` `ret`) is actually generated when the assembler sees a `ret` instruction and transforms it as well.